# Have any theorists argued that imprisonment is an obsolete and unjustified part of a modern society, as a general punishment?

Tags: prison

What if instead of taking it for granted that people who breaks laws have to sit inside confined buildings as punishment, there was a system in place where you lost certain rights because you demonstrated your unwillingness to meet the terms for using that thing? For example, if you drunk drive, you lose road privileges, or the ability to drive on the road, for some period of time; instead of spending time in a specific place (a prison)? In other words, have any theorists argued that imprisonment is essentially extremely “random”, even backwards and archaic?

Comment: seems more suited for SE.Philosophy than Politics.  You picked an easy example, drunk driving with revocation of driving privileges.  Which... drumroll... is already the norm in most cases of drunk driving.  Plenty of other people would offer long lists of non-incarceration punishments.  However, what do you do with harder cases like rape or murder?  What rights would you lose?  Not a political question at this point, since this proposal - no incarceration, ever - isn't seriously proposed  anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This is, in part, the perspective of many people within the [prison abolition movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prison_abolition_movement?wprov=sfla1), whose various ramifications—and associated theorists—are described in some detail on the linked page.

The page quotes the disability and prison researcher Liat Ben-Moshe in describing the movement:

> Many prison abolitionists advocate for transformative justice and
> healing practices in which no one will be restrained or segregated,
> while some, like PREAP, believe that there will always be a small
> percentage of those whose behavior is so unacceptable or harmful that
> they will need to be incapacitated, socially exiled, or restrained and
> that this should be done humanely, temporarily, and not in a carceral
> or punitive manner.

As you can see, the focus is less on depriving people of rights other than freedom of movement, as suggested in the question, and more on some (often lightly quixotic) ideal of a society in which no type of punishment will be needed at all.

However, the mention of prison abolition groups that recognize "social exile" as a possible tool for dealing with the most incorrigible offenders seems to approach the suggestion in the question of reducing people's rights instead of imprisonment.

Comment: Some Islamic scholars (e.g. Jāvēd Aḥmad Ghāmidī) have argued the same, but from a different standpoint, namely that the Koran doesn't talk about it https://journalofislamiclaw.com/current/article/view/zulfiqar2 In subtext, they only want corporal punishments.

Comment: @Fizz - Interesting. And that article illustrates a typical trend: are some useful insights coming from prison abolition advocates, but (when they are not just painting over a radical reformist agenda and truly do intend to eliminate all incarceration) they tend to avoid talking too much about how they propose to effectively substitute prisons. As you say, Ghāmidī's perspective implicitly supports a return to corporal punishment, but the article does not dwell on that as one of the insights that we should take from his work.

Comment: "incarceration is impermissible because it subverts Islamic law by replacing scripturally prescribed, corporal punishment" True, the citation for that is not Ghāmidī but some  Aḥmad al-Naqīb.

Comment: Similarly, many true prison abolitionists tend to avoid talking about the most dedicated killers and other violent criminals and their likelihood of killing again if not contained, and when they do admit the existence of this category, their proposals tend toward "prisons but not": for instance, how can someone be "incapacitated" in a temporary and non-carceral manner, as proposed by PREAP? Presumably through something that would be prison in all but name (unless they just mean bopping them on the head with a cosh, which is certainly temporary and non-carceral, but of arguable humanity).

Comment: @Fizz - Right, that is attributed to al-Naqīb, and *contrasted* with the viewpoint of Ghāmidī, described as rejecting "the idea of long-term imprisonment as a form of punishment because it is fundamentally immoral and, since it is immoral, it is also effectively impermissible under Islamic law." It at least leaves open the possibility that Ghāmidī's alternative to imprisonment does not encompass corporal punishment, but without saying so outright.

Comment: @Fizz - I get the impression that Ghāmidī actually is fine with corporal punishments, as long as they are carried out by the duly elected authorities. In [this interview](https://ghamidi.com/articles/an-interview-with-the-indian-media-442), he says "If I know that the assassin of my father is walking free, I have not received justice and I kill him for myself, or if someone has committed a fraud with me and I cut off his hands myself, it would only promote violence. Punishments are to be given by legal and formal authorities."

Comment: So he's not against capital punishment (or for that matter amputation). Which may be an inconvenient point for the article, because the audience that is reading it is unlikely to want to replace prison with capital punishment or amputation. Perhaps that is why the article kind of glosses over Ghāmidī's actual proposals to replace imprisonment, and focuses on his critique of imprisonment while primarily attributing the recognition of corporal punishment to others.

Comment: "Lightly" quixotic is putting it lightly.

Answer (score 1):

In economics, it is the standard view that fines are better (or "more efficient") than imprisonment.

The intuition is that a fine is simply a transfer payment (with zero or low total costs to society).

In contrast, imprisonment has far larger costs to society (the largest costs are borne by the convict, but there are also the very large costs of imprisoning the convict borne by the rest of society).

See in particular Gary Becker, "Crime and Punishment: An Economic Approach" ([1968](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1830482)) (one of the key works [cited](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/economic-sciences/1992/press-release/) by the Nobel committee).